# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+(1/2))}{4^n(2n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Prove $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4^n\left(2n+1\right)\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}$$
The original sum is multiplied by $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ and so it equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but I pulled the constant out because the actual series troubles me.  I dont know how to evaluate this.  I think maybe the Gammas and $4^n$ simplify and leave some constant divide by $2n+1$ which is the familiar arctan series.  [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20%CE%93%281%2F2%20%2B%20n%29%2F%28%20%CE%93%281%20%2B%20n%29*4%5En*%282n%2B1%29%29%20from%20n%3D0%20to%20inf) can't help simplify it, just compute it.  Any help please?

Comment: Use the fact that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and cancel it from both sides. Perhaps then it will resemble some well known series.

Comment: Or, use $\Gamma(n+1/2) = \sqrt{\pi} (2n)!/(4^n n!)$

Comment: @aschepler So $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{2n \choose n}}{{16}^n (2n+1)}$$
I see it equals $\frac{\pi}{3}$ as desires, but how?

Comment: Perhaps you are aware of the series for $\arcsin x$.  Your series in last comment then evaluates to $x^{-1/2}\arcsin(x^{1/2})$ for $x=1/4$ which is basically $\pi/3$.

Comment: Since $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ can't we replace $\Gamma(n+1)$ with $n!$?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes thats how I got the binomial term in the comment.  Thanks @ Paramanand Singh I did not know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the Taylor series for $\arcsin$.

Begin with
$$
(1-x^2)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} (-1)^k x^{2k}
$$
Integrate term-by-term
$$
\arcsin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}{k}\frac{(-1)^k\;x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
$$
Prove (by induction) that
$$
\binom{-1/2}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k}\;\Gamma(\frac12+k)}{\sqrt{\pi}\; k!}
$$
Thus
$$
\arcsin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}\Gamma(\frac12+k)}{\sqrt{\pi}(2k+1)k!}
$$
Plug in $x=1/2$ to get
$$
\arcsin \frac12 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac12+k)}{4^k(2k+1)k!}
$$
Finally, $\arcsin\frac12 = \frac{\pi}{6}$.
$$
\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac12+k)}{4^k(2k+1)k!}
\\
\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{3} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac12+k)}{4^k(2k+1)k!}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}\sqrt{\pi}, \, \, \Gamma(n+1)=n!$$ and our sum  get simplified to $$\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{16^n(2n+1) (n!)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{16^n(2n+1)}{2n\choose n} $$ Now recall the ordinary generating function of [central binomial coefficients](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) for $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$ , that is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n\choose n} x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\cdots(1)$$ now replacing $x$by $\frac{x^2}{16}$  in $(1)$ we get $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16^n}{2n\choose n}x^{2n} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\cdots(2)$$ Now  we integrating  $(2)$ from $0$ to $1$ gives $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16^n(2n+1)}{2n\choose n} =\int_0^1\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=2\int_0^1\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg|_0^1=\frac{\pi}{3}\cdots(3)$$ now we multiply by the factor $\sqrt{\pi}$  in $(3)$ giving us the desired closed form

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{16^n(2n+1)}{2n\choose n} =\frac{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{n + 1/2} \over 4^n\pars{2n + 1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1}}} =
\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1/2}! \over n!\pars{-1/2}!}\,{\pars{1/4}^{n} \over 2n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}
\,{\pars{1/4}^{n} \over 2n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{- 1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\pars{1 \over 4}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{- 1/2 \choose n}
\pars{-\,{t^{2} \over 4\phantom{^{2}}}}^{n}\,\dd t =
2\root{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \root{4 - t^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pi^{3/2} \over 3} \\ &
\end{align}